# Small footprint Windows XP install on  netbook

Tags: windows-7, installation, netbook, acer-aspire-one

I have a  Aspire One AOA 150 . I want to customize a Windows XP installation ( for e.g with nlite ) for small memory footprint and low CPU usage. then I want to try out [Windows XP embedded](http://207.46.16.252/en-us/magazine/2007.04.xpe.aspx) for performance comparisons. How can I generate a small footprint Windows XP installation? Anyone having similar experience on netbooks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few guides to it such as [this](http://lifehacker.com/374376/trim-down-windows-to-the-bare-essentials)

In addition, use a rewritable cd, in case you remove something you need, so you can tweak the install, and know your hardware.